# CreateProcess() works in cmd but if executed in cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin

i'm working on a c++ project on windows, and i want to use cygwin not as a target environment, but just as a shell for replacing cmd, my project is actually compiled for windows with mingw.

My program for now just execute a CreateProcess, the problem is that if i call it from the cmd it works, if i execute the program from cygwin it does nothing while still the CreateProcess() is returning true.

That's the code:

```
int exec_module(const string& name, HANDLE stdIn, HANDLE stdOut, HANDLE stdErr) {

STARTUPINFO child_sinfo = { sizeof(child_sinfo) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION child_pinfo;
ZeroMemory(&child_sinfo, sizeof(child_sinfo));
child_sinfo.cb = sizeof(child_sinfo);

ZeroMemory(&child_pinfo, sizeof(child_pinfo));

child_sinfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
child_sinfo.hStdInput = stdIn;
child_sinfo.hStdOutput = stdOut;
child_sinfo.hStdError = stdErr;

return CreateProcess(0, _T((char *) name.c_str()), 0, 0, false,0, 0, 0, &child_sinfo, &child_pinfo);
}
```

And i call it like this:

```
if (!exec_module("caccone.exe", GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE))) {
    cout << "Errore durante l'esecuzione del modulo" << endl;
}
```

I just can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Does the shell not use console handles for the standard handles? For example, does it use pipes to simulate a Unix pty? If so try creating inheritable duplicates and call `CreateProcess`   with `TRUE` for `bInheritHandles`.

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but note that `_T((char *)name.c_str())` is wrong; the _T macro only works on string literals.  (I guess you're using the multibyte character set, or it wouldn't even compile.)  Also, in Unicode mode, the command line argument must point to a modifiable buffer, not a constant string.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad here, to work well in cygwin i had to add synchronization code between parent and child, but the cmd shell worked also in a naife way.
Thx Harry Johnston for the point on the _T macro.